# How to Ignore the white Spaces while compare two files?

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, compare

I want to create a Unit test method. Version of Java - 1.6

```
@Test
public void TestCreateHtml() throws IOException{

    final File output = parser.createHtml();
    final File expected = new File("src/main/resources/head.jsp");

  assertEquals("The files differ!", FileUtils.readLines(expected), FileUtils.readLines(output));
}
```

This test method doesn't work.
The contents of both files are equals, but they have different number of white spaces.

How can I ignore the white spaces?

Comment: What kind of white spaces? The ones at the front or the end of a string, or whitespaces between words?

Comment: At the front an the end of a string

Comment: Use the String's `trim` method. This removes the leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: How about replacing them by nothing?

Comment: Why don't you put correct value in your `expected` file?

Answer (score 11):

If the problem is in leading/trailing white space:

```
assertEquals(actual.trim(), expected.trim());
```

If problem is in file contents, only solution I can think of is to remove all white space from both inputs:

```
assertEquals(removeWhiteSpaces(actual), removeWhiteSpaces(expected));
```

where removeWhiteSpaces() method looks like this:

```
String removeWhiteSpaces(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is only leading/trailing white spaces, you can compare line by line after trimming both. This does not work if there can also be extra newlines in one file compared to the other.

```
@Test
public void TestCreateHtml() throws IOException{
    final File output = parser.createHtml();
    final File expected = new File("src/main/resources/head.jsp");

    List<String> a = FileUtils.readLines(expected);
    List<String> b = FileUtils.readLines(output);

    assertEquals("The files differ!", a.size(), b.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        assertEquals("The files differ!", a.get(i).trim(), b.get(i).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over list and trim each line

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s: FileUtils.readLines(expected)) {
    result.add(s.trim());
}
```

Same with other file.

And then compare new lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the leading and trailing whitespace before comparing:

```
@Test
public void TestCreateHtml() throws IOException{

    final File output = parser.createHtml();
    final File expected = new File("src/main/resources/head.jsp");

    assertEquals("The files differ!", FileUtils.readLines(expected).replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", ""), FileUtils.readLines(output).replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", ""));
}
```